# How sum 24 hours to time mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a column time type in mysql, i want to add 24 hours to this hour, i try with code below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('23:00', '%k:%i'), INTERVAL (TIME_TO_SEC('24:00') / 60) MINUTE) AS CHAR(8)), 1,5)
```

I need to return 23:00 again (because i add 24 hours but that 23:00 is of the next day) but this code return me 47:00.
Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for ADDTIME

```
 SELECT ADDTIME(‘23:00’,’24:00’)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime

Comment: How about if you give it a dummy date-time: SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(ADDTIME('2017-01-01 23:00', '24:00'), ' ', -1)

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the column value to a datetime, add the hours, and then convert the result back to time:

```
select cast(date_add(cast(time_column as datetime), interval 24 hour ) as time)
from yourtable;
```

Example:

```
select cast(date_add(cast(cast('23:00' as time) as datetime), interval 24 hour ) as time)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/time.html) type allows you to store up to (but not including) 839 hours (positive and negative). That's great if you need to store duration, but not so much if you want to store time of day. If you want the latter you should consider the `DATETIME` type instead.